# Windows 10 taskbar Folder Location

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 10, I recently changed the location of the Desktop from my C-drive to an external drive.

While this worked, this also caused the items on the taskbar to disappear.
Before this change I had 5 items on my taskbar.
Now when I restart, my taskbar is empty except for the Windows button.

1. Is there a way to fix this issue so I can still access my local taskbar directory?
   I know it is located at `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` and I can confirm it is still populated with the correct shortcuts.
2. Is there a way to change the taskbar folder location to a location on a drive?

Answer (score 2):

i can only imagine this being possible if you happen to find and change the **registry key which holds the path** to the start menu folder.

**i highly doubt you should change it.**

Comment: Any idea where in the registry this is?

Comment: try HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband.  

source: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4636-pin-taskbar-folder-drive-windows-10-a.html   

can you please accept my answer? thanks